# Div appear and disappear onclick in reactjs hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, slice

I want an effect like this [(before onclick)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GRH5.png) then i onclick the red div [(after oncilck)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqpVI.png).Just click on which div to make it disappear, and then let the div that disappeared before show again.

Here is the data code.

```
const leftBarData=
[{
    name:"关于音乐",
    color:"bg-music-color",
    icon:<div className="iconMusicSize">
        
    </div>,
    link:"/music",
    number:0,
    show:true,
},
    {
        name:"关于编程",
        color:"bg-code-color",
        icon:<div className="iconSize"> 
        </div>,
        link:"/code",
        number:1,
        show:true,
    },
    {
        name:"关于设计",
        color:"bg-design-color",
        icon:<div className="iconSize">
            
        </div>,
        link:"/design",
        number:2,
        show:true
    },

]
const leftUnBarData=[
{
    name:"关于本人",
    color:"bg-about-color",
    icon:<div className="iconSize">
       
    </div>,
    link:"/design",
    number:3,
    show:true
}
```

]

Here is map.I just want the div I clicked was replaced by unshow data, and it moved to unshow data not to show.I don't know how to do this.

```
const [statusData,setStatusData]=useState(leftBarData)
const [unShowData,setUnShowData]=useState(leftUnBarData)
const changeBar=(pars)=>
    {
        const temArray=statusData
        temArray.splice(pars.number,1,...unStatusData);
        setUnStatusData(pars)
        setStatusData(temArray);   //it can only work once
    }


return(
    <div  className="flex fixed">
        {statusData?.map((index,i)=>(
            <Link to={index.link}>
                <div className={` ${index.color} ${index.show?"":"hidden"} w-99 h-screen pt-9 `} onClick={()=>changeBar(index)}>
                    <div className="flex flex-col h-full items-center justify-between">
                            {index.icon}
                        <div className="-rotate-90 -translate-y-full mb-10">
                            <div className="h3 text-white whitespace-nowrap">{index.name}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Link>
        ))}
    </div>
```

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your function can't update the second time because the pars in your function is object and the initial state for unShowData is array.
Hope this can help you.

```
const changeBar=(pars, i)=>
  {
      const datas = [...statusData]
      datas[i] = unShowData[0]
      setUnShowData([pars])
      setStatusData(datas)
  }
```

And update the onClick function to:

```
onClick={()=>changeBar(index, i)}
```